# Does $[\alpha][\gamma]\tilde{x_0}=[\beta][\gamma]\tilde{x_0}$ imply $[\alpha]\tilde{x_0}=[\beta]\tilde{x_0}$ in a fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Does $[\alpha][\gamma]\tilde{x_0}=[\beta][\gamma]\tilde{x_0}$ imply $[\alpha]\tilde{x_0}=[\beta]\tilde{x_0}$ in a fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$?

$\alpha,\beta $ and $\gamma$ are the loops based at $x_0$ and $\tilde{x_0}=p^{-1}(x_0)$ is the lift of $x_0$ through the covering map.

Comment: "the usual meaning" is too vague. I'm assuming that $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are loops in $X$ based at $x_0$, with $[\alpha]$, $[\beta]$, and $[\gamma]$ denoting their respective equivalence classes in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$, but what does the "$x_0$" in "$[\alpha]x_0$" mean?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Your notation is stilll hard to understand, even after the edit. I know that $[\alpha]$ represents the path homotopy class of the path $\alpha$ in $X$. And I know that $\tilde x_0$ represents a point in the covering space of $X$. But I do not know what it means when you put them side by side in your notation $[\alpha] \tilde x_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. For example take the covering as in the picture below. Take $\gamma = b$, $\alpha = a\cdot b$,  $\beta=b$ and $\tilde{x_0}=y_2$. Then $[\gamma]\tilde{x_0}=y_1$ and then $[\alpha]([\gamma]\tilde{x_0})=[\beta]([\gamma]\tilde{x_0})=y_2$ but $$[\alpha]\tilde{x_0}=y_3\neq y_1=[\beta]\tilde{x_0}.$$

[image]